# Dataframe with list of functions as a column

Tags: r, dataframe, purrr

I'm trying to organize simulated data from different distributions into a tidy dataframe. My following code can generate dataframe with a row for each distribution, a column that is a list of functions, and a column that is a list of simulated data <s>matrices</s> dataframes.

```
library(tidyverse)
N = 1000
nreps = 100

simDF <- data.frame(
  distr = c('normal', 'gamma12', 'gamma22'),
  FUN = I(list(normal = function(x) rnorm(x), gamma12 = function(x) rgamma(x, shape = 1, scale = 2), gamma22 = function(x) rgamma(x, shape = 2, scale = 2)))
)

sim_data <- function(FUN, N, nreps) return(data.frame(matrix(rnorm(N), nrow = N, ncol = nreps)))

simDF <- simDF %>% 
  mutate(data = map(FUN, function(f) sim_data(f, N, nreps)))
```

When I try to view the dataframe, with either the default `print` or `glimpse`, I get the error:

> Error in paste(x, collapse = ", ") :    cannot coerce type 'closure'
>   to vector of type 'character'

I can work with the dataframe as it is, but I cannot get get the nice [console printouts for nested dataframes](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html) and I feel like there's a better way (possibly w closures?). Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `tidyverse`, use a `tibble` rather than a `data.frame`. `data.frames` really only like atomic vectors as columns. But `tibbles` have different print methods that are more tolerant of "unusual" content.

```
simDF <- tibble(
  distr = c('normal', 'gamma12', 'gamma22'),
  FUN = list(normal = function(x) rnorm(x), gamma12 = function(x) rgamma(x, shape = 1, scale = 2), gamma22 = function(x) rgamma(x, shape = 2, scale = 2))
)
```

Comment: Ah so simple. I think I assumed that my `mutate` calls would get me a `tibble` in the end.